# zsh: What does hist_find_no_dups mean?

Tags: zsh

> ```
>   HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
>          When searching for history entries in the line editor, do not display duplicates of a line previously found, even if  the  duplicates  are  not contiguous.
> ```

However, when I use Ctrl-p repeatedly, same command appears.

```
$ ls
$ pwd
$ ls
$ <Ctrl-p> => ls 
  <Ctrl-p> => pwd
  <Ctrl-p> => ls  again!
```

zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hist_find_no_dups` doesn't guarantee that all lines will by unique, you might be searching back through repeated pair of lines.

If you don't want to have duplicate lines  then look into `hist_ignore_all_dups`. It will stop repeated commands from appearing in your history file but it might introduce unexpected gaps - something to be aware of if you're reusing parts of your history.

Another option to look into is `hist_ignore_dups`. This prevents consecutive duplicates from being saved.

Last, but not least, there's `hist_save_no_dups` (ignores duplicates when writing history file) and `hist_expire_dups_first`, which will start removing repeating commands when limit of `$HISTSIZE` will be reached.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-P` is the same as up arrow, it allows you to access previous commands written in history.

`HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS` makes an effect when you **search** for previous commands by pressing `Ctrl+R`, it will skip duplicates.

Comment: Ie, if you enter commands, `cd ~/Downloads`, `cd`, `cd ~/Download`, `cd /`. Then hit Ctrl-r, type `cd` then hit Ctrl-r to cycle though matches, you will only see `cd ~/Downloads` appear once if you have set `HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS`